# WCF Message Inspector - modify invalid XML SOAP response

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm calling a SOAP service using a WCF client in .NET.
It sometimes happens that the SOAP service is sending back a response that can't be serialized to the .NET objects. The main culprit here is a datetime field in which they are sending back "24:00:00" instead of "00:00:00".

In this case, we get back the following error: "The DateTime represented by the string is not supported in calendar System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar."

In order to solve this, I implemented a WCF Message Inspector, where I want to modify the message in the "AfterReceiveReply" method. Here I would like to find the incorrect date and correct it, before sending it back to the client.

I would do the replacement through string manipulation (find + replace).

However, I am not able to retrieve the content of the reply message as a string..
I tried doing this through "reply.GetReaderAtBodyContents()" and then get the "OuterXml", but this ends up crashing with the same error as above, since it's reading it as an XML object (and it contains an invalid date).

[image: exception details]

I also tried following, but there I have the same issue as well (since we can't write invalid XML to the XmlWrite object), it throws the same error as above.

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(ms);
reply.WriteMessage(xw);
xw.Flush();
string body = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
xw.Close();
```

The Message object only accepts an "XmlWriter" or "XmlDictionaryWriter" to write to a different stream: 
[image: code snippet]

Any ideas how I can get the raw body content of the reply message as a string object, without parsing it as an XML Document?

Thanks in advance!

Best regards

Comment: Maybe instead of using a XmlWriter you resort to a string writer and correct the contents that way? I think any form of XML parser will fail on validation and you'd have to fix it before parsing. Just my 2 cents

Comment: Thx for the comment. Indeed but I am not able to write the stream to a string writer. The message object only accepts an XmlWriter object. So I want to find a way to use StringWriter instead of XmlWriter (I updated my question a bit with this info)

Comment: The XML it self has no knowledge about "types". It shouldn't know that an element represents a date unless you give it an XML Schema. Can you share the stack trace when it crashes when you do a GetReaderAtBodyContents .

Comment: Message needs to be treated as immutable. You need to create a new Message with one of the `Message.CreateMessage` overloads, and assign it to `reply` (that is why `reply` is a `ref`)

Comment: I added the error details in my initial question. When using "GetReaderAtBodyContents" and calling the "ReadOuterXml" function, it throws the datetime exception. I tried using one of the other available methods, like "reader.ReadContentAsString()" but this just returns an empty string.

Comment: Can you show the XML node and its parent that has this weird date in it.

Answer (score 1):

If we assume the XmlDictionary that you get from GetReaderAtBodyContents isn't validating by itself, maybe this careful XmlReader that ignores FormatExceptions might be enough to get your dateTime rewritten.

Here is the implementation:

```
void AfterReceiveReply(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message reply, object state) 
{
    // settings to ignore errors ...
    XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
    settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
    settings.ValidationEventHandler += (o,e) => { 
        if (e.Exception != null && !(e.Exception.InnerException is FormatException))
        {
          throw e.Exception;
        }
    }; // ignore formatexception errors

    var xmlrdr = XmlReader.Create(reply.GetReaderAtBodyContents(),settings);
    var ms = new MemoryStream();
    using(var wr = XmlWriter.Create(ms))
    while(xmlrdr.Read())
    {
        // very simple and naive xml copy
         switch(xmlrdr.NodeType) 
         {
             case XmlNodeType.Element:
                 wr.WriteStartElement(xmlrdr.Name);
             break;
             case XmlNodeType.Text:
                 var text = xmlrdr.ReadContentAsString();
                 // names of nodes that are a date
                 if (xmlrdr.Name == "date") 
                 {
                     DateTime dtm;
                     if (!DateTime.TryParse(text, out dtm)) 
                     {
                         // let's assume this is the only thing that can go wrong
                         text = text.Replace("24:00:00", "23:59:59");
                     }
                     wr.WriteString(text);
                     wr.WriteEndElement(); // yeah, well, let's gamble
                 } 
                 else
                 {
                     wr.WriteString(text);
                 }
             break;
             case XmlNodeType.EndElement:
                 wr.WriteEndElement();
             break;
             default:
               // Debug.Assert
             break;
         }
    }
    ms.Position=0;
    // create a new message for the next handler
    reply = System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message.CreateMessage(
       reply.Version, 
       reply.Headers.Action, 
       XmlReader.Create(ms));

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but it still fails on the "xmlrdr.Read()" part with the FormatException. Since the cases where the service sends back the time "24:00:00" is very limited, we decided to catch the exception and leave it as is (someone will manually handle these failed events). Thanks for the help anyway!